# Update using the value from the closest row

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, update, self-join

My table looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
   id  |  name  | housename    | houseno 
-----------------------------------------
   1   | John   | John's House |  2/22
-----------------------------------------
   2   | Rachel | John's House |  2/22
-----------------------------------------
   3   | Joy    | John's House |  
-----------------------------------------
   4   | Alex   | Alex's House |  
-----------------------------------------
   5   | Rachel | Alex's House |  3/22
-----------------------------------------
   6   | Ben    | Alex's House |  3/22
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to update missing `houseno` values by matching with previous or next rows with the same `housename`. Using the example above, for id 3 the `houseno` should be 2/22 (the `houseno` of John's house) and for id 4 it should be `3/22`. The `id` column is the primary key and is **not continuous**.

Which of these two approaches – `min(id) > id` or `id < id order by id desc limit 1` – would work fine for retrieving the previous row?

### Update

Sorry for making the question not clear  , `DISTINCT` cannot be used as there is a chance for the housename to recur . The table can be like the one below ......

```
-----------------------------------------
   id  |  name  | housename    | houseno 
-----------------------------------------
   1   | John   | John's House |  2/22
-----------------------------------------
   2   | Rachel | John's House |  2/22
-----------------------------------------
   3   | Joy    | John's House |  
-----------------------------------------
   4   | Alex   | Alex's House |  
-----------------------------------------
   5   | Rachel | Alex's House |  3/22
-----------------------------------------
   6   | Ben    | Alex's House |  3/22
-----------------------------------------
   7   | John Doe   | John's House |  
-----------------------------------------
   8   | Betty Doe | John's House |  4/22
-----------------------------------------
   9   | Sophy Doe    | John's House | 4/22  
-----------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to group rows without houseno with previous and next  ?

Comment: So you want to fill the gaps when `housename` is present and `houseno` is empty?

Comment: What happens if there are 3 or more consecutive rows without `houseno`?

Comment: @McNets let it be left as such for now  .........  :)

Answer (score 4):

The following approach will only work as expected if we can safely assume that rows with the same `housename` will have the same `houseno` where `houseno` is populated.

As the first step, you need to get the list of all distinct `housename`/`houseno` pairs where `houseno` has a value. If my assumption above is correct, you will get a result set where all `housename` values are unique, and each will have a corresponding `houseno` – a kind of reference table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  housename,
  houseno
FROM
  YourTable
WHERE
  houseno <> ''
```

Use the above as a derived table to join it back to the original table in the UPDATE statement, so that you can populate the missing values from the derived table:

```
UPDATE
  YourTable AS t
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      housename,
      houseno
    FROM
      YourTable
    WHERE
      houseno <> ''
  ) AS ref ON t.housename = ref.housename
SET
  t.houseno = ref.houseno
WHERE
  t.houseno = '' OR t.houseno IS NULL
;
```

Note that rather than "fixing" your table like this, it would be better to normalise it by creating an actual reference table with columns `housename` and `houseno` that you would then join back to your data table whenever you need to retrieve `houseno`. Consequently, the `houseno` column in the original table would no longer be needed.

Comment: Rows with same housename **do** have the same houseno ....

Comment: What do you think about using `LIKE`  instead of strict comparison ?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is chance for housename to get repeated , and that will give the wrong houseno . The db has people arranged house wise in order .

Comment: @AnoopD: I missed a very important part, even though I had it in my mind all the time. Sorry about that. Updated the answer now, please take a look.

Comment: @AnoopD in the first comment you say that *"Rows with same housename do have the same houseno"*. In the second, you say the opposite. Which of the two is true? I guess the second, that rows with same housename may have different houseno, as your updated sample shows.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  Yea you are right , what i meant by the first comment was that ' A house is with unique house number ' but i found after Andriy M gave the solution that the housename is not unique  ( That is why i was trying to group previous and next rows and get the comparison ..... there can be a chance that all three rows  don't have house number , but certainly repeating the query will give the result ) .

Answer (score 1):

That can be done by stored routine:

```
BEGIN 
  SET @prevname = ''
    , @prevno   = ''
  ;

  UPDATE table AS w
     SET w.houseno = IF( @prevname = @prevname := w.housename, 
                         @prevno, 
                         @prevno := w.houseno 
                       )
   ORDER BY w.housename ASC
          , w.houseno DESC
  ;
END
```

There are three tricks here.

First is that `User-Defined Variables` (UDVs) are persistent through the rows proceeding. Once assigned they will store the value until reassigned.

Second is that in context of UDVs there is difference between comparison `=` and assignment `:=` that have different precedence. Here

```
IF( @prevname = @prevname := w.housename,
```

means: IF previously assigned value of `@prevname` is equal to the freshly assigned value of `@prevname` THEN ...

Third is that rows are ordered in the ASC-DESC order. If any row with the same `housename` have `houseno` assigned, it will be proceeded first and propagate its value to the all consequent rows. If you have assigned two different values to the any two rows with the same `housename` by mistake the alphabetically bigger value wiil be propagated across the group.